# troubles with pandas anaconda package

Tags: python, pandas, sublimetext2, spyder

I got a new mac and just installed anaconda. When I use `ipython` and `spyder`, I can `import pandas` without any problem. However, when I use `sublime`, I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

`which python` gives `//anaconda/bin/python`.
Also, `pandas` is listed in `conda list`.
I am using `Anaconda2 4.1.1` and `python 2.7.12`. Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you using Sublime Text 2? While it won't solve your current issue, users are strongly encouraged to use [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3) instead. All development work is now focused on ST3 - [*`"I don't know of any good reason to not use Sublime Text 3"`*](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4) - Will Bond, ST core developer. Additionally, ST2 is [no longer the default download](https://sublimetext.com).

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two line in your .bash_profile, (if you are on bash) export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and source it, or restart the terminal. Or if you are using "oh my zsh" shell, then add the lines in .zshrc.

Comment: I installed sublime text 3 and it worked. It could be a bug in sublime text 2.